# Tensorflow 2 generator make training slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generator

I am working on a supervised regression problem with time series data of power consumption. At first I just used the power consumption (one single time series) that I splitted into windows of 180 data points, 1 data point every minute resulting in a 3 hours long window for the input data. I want to predict the next hour of data (60 data points).

I managed to run several models (dense, lstm & gru mainly) on the gpu using docker. When doing so, training on the gpu resulted in a considerable decrease in training time (4 to 5 times faster) than training on the cpu. The gpu percentage usage was around 30%.

I now want to improve the models by using added features such as day of the week, hour of the day, and minute of the hour. Each of these has been transform to show the cyclical behavior of these features using cosine and sine function (see https://towardsdatascience.com/cyclical-features-encoding-its-about-time-ce23581845ca). So I end up having a sine and a cosine value for each of these features (so 6 variables total plus the consommation value to make it 7). Each example is now a `numpy` array of `shape (180,7)` for the input and `(60,)` for the label. As a result, my dataset grew significantly and does not fit into memory anymore. I have about 90k example for training, 30k for validation and 30k for testing. To overcome this issue I tried using a generator.

However, this resulted in a slower training time than training on the gpu this time, and the gpu usage is much lower, fluctuating between 0% and 8~9%. My batch size is already 256 and increasing it didn't seem to have any effect. From what I read the slow training might be a consequence of reading the files on the disk to generate the batchs.

How could I decrease training time?

Here is the generator

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Custom_Generator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence) :
  
  def __init__(self, example_filenames, example_labels, batch_size, type="train") :
    self.example_filenames = example_filenames
    self.example_labels = example_labels
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.type = type
    
  def __len__(self) :
    return (np.ceil(len(self.example_filenames) / float(self.batch_size))).astype('int')
  
  
  def __getitem__(self, idx) :
    batch_x = self.example_filenames[idx * self.batch_size : (idx+1) * self.batch_size]
    batch_y = self.example_labels[idx * self.batch_size : (idx+1) * self.batch_size]
    
    return(
      np.array([np.load(f'Donnees_Multivariate_to_batch/{self.type}/{str(X_file_name)}') for X_file_name in batch_x]), 
      np.array([np.load(f'Donnees_Multivariate_to_batch/{self.type}/{str(y_file_name)}') for y_file_name in batch_y])
    )
```